# Form if options selected, show custom content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a form where there are 2 select tags, each one has 2 options.

The way it works is:

User selects 1 option (OPTION 1/OPTION 2) and then selects another (OPTION 
A/OPTION B)

Depending on what he selects, it's going to display a custom paragraph

So, if the user selects OPTION 1 and OPTION B, a custom content will be displayed. But this will change if he changes the OPTIONS

[image]

But I can't make it work... Here is my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <p>I am a</p>
    <div class="youare">
        <select name="select" id="select">    
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php 
              $colors = array("Individual", "Business"); 
              foreach ($colors as $value) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$value?>"><?=$value?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p>My pathway is</p>
    <div class="pathway">
        <select name="select" id="select2">    
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php 
                $colors = array("Commercial Property", "Building Surveying"); 
                foreach ($colors as $value) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$value?>"><?=$value?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="button">Select a bundle </a>

</form>



<section id="content">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#select2").change(function(){
        selectVal = $(this).val();
        myarray = ["Individual", "Business"];
        mypath = ["Commercial Property", "Building Surveying"];
        if($.inArray(selectVal, myarray, mypath) !== -1){

          //If option 1 and option A: Show this
        }
        else if {
          //If option 1 and option B: Show this
        }
        else{
          //Do something
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <p class="icp">Content 1</p>
  <p class="ibs">Content 2</p>


</section>
```

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass two arrays to $.inArray(), it takes a value to search for, the array to search, and the index of the array from which to start the search (optional, defaults to zero if not passed), please read the documentation of $.inArray() here (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), to fix your code you need to change it to something like this:

```
$("#select2").change(function(){
    const selectVal = $(this).val();
    const mypath = ["Commercial Property", "Building Surveying"];

if($.inArray(selectVal, mypath , 0) !== -1){ //Start the search at the beginning of the array
         //We have an option selected in drop down 2
         //Lets get drop down one's value
        const dropDown1Val = $('#select').val();

        if(selectVal === "Commercial Property" && dropDown1Val === "Individual"){
          //Show relevant text
        }
        else if (selectVal === "Commercial Property" && dropDown1Val === "Business") {
           //Show relevant text
        }
        else if (selectVal === "Building Surveying" && dropDown1Val === "Individual"){
           //Show relevant text
        }
        else if (selectVal === "Building Surveying" && dropDown1Val === "Business"){
            //Show relevant text
        }
        else{
          //both drop downs are not set, don't show any text??
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

add `selectVal2 = $('#select').val();` in `select2 onchange click`

and compare array value using two different condition like

```
$.inArray(selectVal, mypath) !== -1 && $.inArray(selectVal2, myarray) !== -1
```

using this if user select option first and after second select option if match return `success` else `not match` return

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select2").change(function() {
    selectVal = $(this).val();
    selectVal2 = $('#select').val();
    myarray = ["Individual", "Business"];
    mypath = ["Commercial Property", "Building Surveying"];
    if ($.inArray(selectVal, mypath) !== -1 && $.inArray(selectVal2, myarray) !== -1) {
      console.log('match success');
      //If option 1 and option A: Show this
    } else {
      console.log('not match');
      //Do something
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <p>I am a</p>
  <div class="youare">
    <select name="select" id="select">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
      <option value="option-2">option-2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p>My pathway is</p>
  <div class="pathway">
    <select name="select" id="select2">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="Commercial Property">Commercial Property</option>
      <option value="option-A">option-B</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="button">Select a bundle </a>

</form>



<section id="content">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  <p class="icp">Content 1</p>
  <p class="ibs">Content 2</p>


</section>
```